# Jumping to next tab

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a tab control in my WPF application with multiple tabs. Each tab gives access to several buttons, text boxes, drop downs. Now before moving to the next tab valid entries in each of the controls in the tab is to be checked or jumping to the next tab should not be allowed. How can this be done?

I was able to use IsEnable property to do this. But I want it like, when I click on the next tab it should, without entering the next tab, display a warning that such and such entry in the present tab is not valid.

Comment: I dont want to disable the next tab. I have used a message box to display warning. But when i click the tab, it enters it. It should stay on the present tab itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you adhere to the `Selected` event you can do something like this:

```
// Keep a global variable for the previous index
int prevIndex = 0;

private void tabControl_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tc = sender as TabControl;
    if (tc != null)
    {
        bool letSwitchHappen = validateTabControls(tc.SelectedIndex);
        if (!letSwitchHappen)
        {
            tc.SelectedIndex = prevIndex;
        }
        prevIndex = tc.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Where `validateTabControls` is something like:

```
private bool validateTabControls(int tabIndex)
{
    bool validEntries = false;
    // Some code here to set validEntries according to the control at tabIndex
    return validEntries;
}
```

Comment: I did not find "Selected" event in System.Windows.Controls.TabControl for WPF. I found it for windows forms System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

Comment: Whoops, try the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example from Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/how-to-prevent-a-tabitem-from-being-selected/).

It shows explicitly how to do this, and Josh is well-known (and respected) in the WPF world.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it was probably because your answer contains no explanation about the problem or the solution, and is just a link to an external resource

Comment: @Rachel - I did that because the work is not mine, and is simply among the examples I found when I Googled.  It's a slight improvement on a LMGTFY.  I will update the answer a bit, but I don't want copy the contents of an external resource that is not my own and take credit for it.

Comment: +1 to fightthe down vote since the link addresses the issue. @WonkotheSane I would reference the link and copy the core element(s) to you post.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Its OK to copy/paste solutions here providing you give credit to the original author. You never know when an external link will go down or change, and then a link-only answer becomes useless (I've had this happen to a few great WPF links I found, and I'm glad I have copies of the relevant code on here)